# Load dynamic content with Ajax and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I would like to implement the following project. The page has a navigation bar with several items. The content of each tab should be displayed without reloading the page. I use Nodejs with the ejs template engine. I have done a lot of research, but I couldn't find a solution. I think you have to send an Ajax request to the server and it sends back the needed html part. Can anyone help me with an example? I understood it logically, but I can't directly implement it yet. If you need any further information to help me feel free to write me.

Regards.

Comment: you want the content to appear on the same page right? Like click on about us page and some dynamic content would be loaded to the same page deleting the previous contents?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The NodeJS server app should only send you JSON data, for example. All the HTML element you need can be dynamically created using JavaScript, you just need to insert the recently created data into your HTML elements.

This is just an brief example:

```
<div id="div1">
    <p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>

<script>
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("div1");
    element.appendChild(para);
</script>
```

Comment: I thought about something like this where I just response with the partial of the site which should be replaced.



`app.get('/navitem', function (req, res) {
    //compute data here
    res.render('navitem', {layout: false, data: data});
});`

Answer (score 0):

For an effective solution you can use two npm modules at first to help you sending right data.

Let's say you want to send html format of some dynamic data you would want to use html/pug/ejs/handlebars to send data because there you can send the data too if your router requires processing.

You can use [node-email-templates](https://github.com/niftylettuce/node-email-templates) to convert html from other platform, and also **inline css** to the html from the css file. Refer to the link to know more.

Though you are not sending an email, yet you can use it.

Now, you would want to send this from your route, here are examples: https://github.com/niftylettuce/node-email-templates/tree/master/examples

Now, you had generated the html format which has css inline attached to it, and you need to send the generated HTML `result.html` as the response, but you need to know which data to render according to the request, so you may need to set multiple routes or you can do it one using `params` or `query`:

I am mainly using it for embedding css inline to the html, but you can simply do `res.send()` and use css IN YOUR main html though (where you are receiving it).

#### Router

```
var EmailTemplate = require('email-templates').EmailTemplate;
var path = require('path');
router.get('/api/:page', function(req, res){
 if (req.params.page == 'home')
 {
  //set the directory to your html here : /views/home contains html.pug      
  // and style.css
  var templateDir = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'views', 'home');

  var page = new EmailTemplate(templateDir);
 }

 var user = {name: 'Joe', pasta: 'spaghetti'}

 page.render(user, function (err, result) {
   // NOTE: I am passing user object which you can use to render data same as res.render('', user: user).
   // so in your template user.name will be rendered as Joe and user.pasta will be rendered as spaghetti

   // result.html
   res.status(200).send(result.html);
 });
});
```

---

And now you can use jquery AJAX or axios whichever your prefer to receive data and apply.

#### HTML:

You can append `data-page` to your links(or whatever in which you want the user to click) and set it to appropriate value.

```
...
<li class="nav-links"><a href="#" data-page="home">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav-links"><a href="#" data-page="about">About</a></li>
...
<div class="main-content">
 <!-- content to be added here -->
</div>
...
```

#### JS

I am using jQuery.

```
$('.nav-links a').click(function(e){

 var page = $(this).attr('data-page');

 $.ajax({
  method: "get",
  url: "/api/"+page,
  success: function(response){
   $('.main-content').empty().append(response);
  }
 });

});
```

Hope it helps. :)